# Optimal point distribution within polygons

Tags: qgis, point-in-polygon

I have a polygon and want to distribute a certain number of points within that polygon. The Points should have almost the same distance to each other and also to the boundary.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the information that I'm using QGIS.

Comment: Not a very meticulous method but you could create a negative buffer (**Fixed distance buffer** tool) with your distance whilst setting a high value for segments (useful for polygons so that it maintains much of its vertices). And then create your random points inside this buffer by setting the number of points and minimum distance (**Random points in layer bounds** tool).

Comment: I tried this but the resut is not really what I want to get. If I would have a field and want to grow Cristmas trees (each should have enough space to grow without touching the next or overlapping the fence around the field). I need to find the optimal seed points.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Questions: 1. How are your polygons shaped? 2. How do you want to arrange your trees? Do you want to optimize cultivation (using rows, paths between them). What is the benefit from this? Do you plant your trees with the help of GPS if the positions of trees are not arranged in rows?

Comment: The trees are just an example for a better understanding. Actually I need to find out how to distribute a known number of points within a polygon. i found many examples in the www. I attach a pic that shows actually what I need to have. I put the points almost accurate inside the polygon and used voronoi polygons to show the equal areas around the points.

Answer (score 2):

This could be solution:

1. If you have irregular polygon create the `Oriented minimum bounding box` (Search for it in the Processing Toolbox):

[image]

2. Create a point grid with `Regular Points` (Processing Toolbox). Use the Bounding Box as the Input Extent.

[image]

[image]

3. Activate the Edit Mode of the new point layer and select the points and rotate them with the `Advanced Digitizing Toolbar`. The angle can be set or estimated during rotation.
4. Set a negative Buffer for the Polygon to have the distance to the boundary (See `Fixed Distance Buffer`)
5. Intersect the points with the buffer with the `Intersection` Tool

This could be the result:

[image]